# how to implement a file name completion in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, registry

Recently, I want to make a library to operate the Windows registry.

The first thing I want to do is making the input of registry key path easily. Since it looks like a file path, maybe this can be achieved by methods like `read-file-name'? Every time the user input the`/' and push  key, I can use the `reg query' shell command get the next possible sub keys.

But how to make it really in real emacs lisp code?

Or maybe there is already a full functional library?

Answer (score 1):

You'll basically have to write a "completion-table" for your registry keys.  I don't think this completion table already exists in Emacs.  You can use the code of `completion-file-name-table` as inspiration.